Minimizing a Function with Nonlinear Constraints
I am trying to minimize the function  $f(x, y) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$  subject to the constraints:
$$
x + \frac{x}{x + y} y - c \leq 0,
$$
$$
x \geq 0,
$$
$$
y \geq 0.
$$
I have attempted to use the method of Lagrange multipliers but encountered difficulties due to the complexity of the constraints. Here are the steps I have taken so far:

Defined the Lagrangian:
$$ \mathcal{L}(x, y, \lambda, \mu, \nu) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y} - \lambda \left( x + \frac{x}{x + y} y - c \right) + \mu x + \nu y$$
Computed the partial derivatives and set them to zero:
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x} = -\frac{1}{x^2} - \lambda \left( 1 + \frac{y^2}{(x + y)^2} \right) + \mu = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y} = -\frac{1}{y^2} - \lambda \left( \frac{x^2}{(x+y)^2} \right) + \nu = 0$$
Complementary slackness conditions
$$\lambda( x + \frac{x}{x + y} y - c) = 0$$
$$\mu x = 0$$
$$\nu y = 0$$
And $$\lambda \ge 0, \mu \ge 0, \nu \ge 0$$
I am unsure how to proceed from here. Could someone guide me on how to approach this problem, or suggest a numerical method that could help solve it?


I can show that the infimum is $\frac{2}{c}$, but it is not achieved (you get it when $x = \frac{c}{2}$, $y\to \infty$). But I think this question is better be moved to MSE first.

$f$ is not defined where $x=0$ or $y=0$, so instead of $x \geq 0$ and $y \geq 0$, we can use $x > 0$ and $y > 0$.
Let's consider the region in the plane where
$$ x + \frac{xy}{x+y} - c \leq 0 $$
First, since $\frac{xy}{x+y} > 0$, we know $x < c$ (and also $c>0$).
Multiplying by $x+y$ (which is positive),
$$ x^2 + 2xy - cx - cy \leq 0 $$
$$ (2x-c)y \leq cx - x^2 $$
Since $0 < x < c$, $cx - x^2 > 0$. So if $2x-c \leq 0$, the inequality is satisfied for any positive $y$. This gives Case 1:
$$ 0 < x \leq \frac c2 \mbox{ and } y > 0 $$
Otherwise, the inequality gives Case 2:
$$ \frac c2 < x \leq c \mbox{ and } y \leq \frac{cx-x^2}{2x-c} $$
In Case 1, $x \geq \frac c2$ immediately gives
$$ f(x,y) = \frac 1x + \frac 1y > \frac 2c $$
In Case 2,
$$ f(x,y) = \frac 1x + \frac 1y \geq \frac 1x + \frac{2x-c}{cx-x^2} = \frac{1}{c-x} > \frac 2c $$
For any $\epsilon>0$, we can get $f(x,y) = \frac 2c + \epsilon$ from $x = \frac c2, y = \frac 1 \epsilon$, satisfying Case 1. Therefore $f$ has no absolute minimum.
The Lagrangian approach fails since there is no point $(x,y)$ in the region where $f(x,y)$ is even a relative minimum.
